# How do you sort a list with string and numbers

Tags: python, list, bubble-sort

hi im new to python and was wondering how i can sort by the price going from biggest to smallest but im not sure how to do that without just switching the order of the items and cost in the list

```
Item1 = input("What item do you want to buy? ") # asking what item is
Cost1 = float(input("How much does this item cost? ")) # asking cost of item

Item2 = input("What item do you want to buy? ")
Cost2 = float(input("How much does this item cost? "))

Item3 = input("What item do you want to buy? ")
Cost3 = float(input("How much does this item cost? "))

Item4 = input("What item do you want to buy? ")
Cost4 = float(input("How much does this item cost? "))

Item5 = input("What item do you want to buy? ")
Cost5 = float(input("How much does this item cost? "))

List = [(Item1, Cost1), (Item2, Cost2), (Item3, Cost3), (Item4, Cost4), (Item5, Cost5)] # making a list of other lists

#bubble sort function so it prints in the correct order
def bubble_sort(List):  
    # Outer loop for traverse the entire list  
    for i in range(0,len(List)-1):  
        for j in range(len(List)-1):  
            if(List[j]<List[j+1]):  
                temp = List[j]  
                List[j] = List[j+1]  
                List[j+1] = temp  
    return List  
  
print("Your shopping list is: ",bubble_sort(List))
```

Comment: Please explain the problem with your code.

Comment: *im not sure how to do that without just switching the order* How can you sort without switching the order? it's kind of necessary...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for provided example,
once you have all inputs, just sort by price and that's all

```
sorted_by_ = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
```

`reverse=True` will sort descending, since you want from biggest to smallest.

> [Key functions (docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

Answer (score 0):

The individual elements of a tuple t=(item, cost) can be accessed using indexing, so that t[0] refers to the item in t and t[1] to the cost in t. Thus, you can replace the condition List[j]<List[j+1] by List[j][1]<List[j+1][1], in order to compare their second components; see code below.

```
Item1 = input("What item do you want to buy? ") # asking what item is
Cost1 = float(input("How much does this item cost? ")) # asking cost of item

Item2 = input("What item do you want to buy? ")
Cost2 = float(input("How much does this item cost? "))

Item3 = input("What item do you want to buy? ")
Cost3 = float(input("How much does this item cost? "))

Item4 = input("What item do you want to buy? ")
Cost4 = float(input("How much does this item cost? "))

Item5 = input("What item do you want to buy? ")
Cost5 = float(input("How much does this item cost? "))

List = [(Item1, Cost1), (Item2, Cost2), (Item3, Cost3), (Item4, Cost4), (Item5, Cost5)] # making a list of other lists

#bubble sort function so it prints in the correct order
def bubble_sort(List):  
    # Outer loop for traverse the entire list  
    for i in range(0,len(List)-1):  
        for j in range(len(List)-1):  
            if(List[j][1]<List[j+1][1]):  
                temp = List[j]  
                List[j] = List[j+1]  
                List[j+1] = temp  
    return List  
  
print("Your shopping list is: ",bubble_sort(List))
```

Comment: ah so basically the extra [1] in if(List[j][1]<List[j+1][1]): makes it so it looks at the second thing in the list instead of the first one. Thanks a lot very much appreciated. :) and everything works